# Capture network traffic in C#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, fiddler, winpcap

I'm using Selenium, and I'm wishing to capture all cookie packets sent during a page request. I've come across Fiddler core, and a few other derivatives, but can't seem to locate any working examples. Have been working on this with no progress for almost 10 hours so any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: You've failed to identify your actual problem. FiddlerCore ships with a sample application that will capture all HTTP headers, including Cookie and Set-Cookie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BrowserMob Proxy](http://opensource.webmetrics.com/browsermob-proxy/) is (quote):

> A free utility to help web developers watch and manipulate network
>   traffic from their web applications

I've co-written a .NET library to make it simple to work with that proxy. The code is up on [GitHub here](https://github.com/AutomatedTester/AutomatedTester.BrowserMob) and I've blogged a bit more about it, with example code, [here](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2012/02/automating-web-performance-stats.html). So with those 2 components, and Selenium, hopefully you can get the information you need.

Information is provided in the HAR format, for which you can see details of [here](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/). Basically, for a request/response you can retrieve all the information of what is going across the network, cookies, timings etc.

Hopefully this is the kind of thing you are after.

e.g. basic example to iterate through each request cookie for each HAR log entry:

```
foreach(var entry in harData.Log.Entries)
{
    foreach (var cookie in entry.Request.Cookies)
    {
        string name = cookie.Name;
        string value = cookie.Value;

        // Do something exciting....or just write the values to Console :)
        Console.Write("Cookie name={0}, value={1}, name, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Have been playing with Browser-Mob proxy for the last 30 mins or so. Using the following example: http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2012_02_01_archive.html I don't know how to proceed after: HarResult harData = client.GetHar();

Comment: You should be able to drill down through the object to find the cookies from the request & response (harData.Log.Entries[].Request.Cookies[] / Response.Cookies[])

Comment: Apologies. I'm going to need more of a broken down approach if possible (not great at C#). 

I've created a var variable: var ent = harData.Log.Entries;

Now I need to somehow get at the cookie entires.

Also, the values in Cookie fild (through debugging) all seem to show: Cookies = {AutomatedTester.BrowserMob.HAR.Cookie[0]}

Comment: I've added a basic snippet to my answer that should hopefully get you in the right area.

Comment: Thanks. Got it executing and outputting results. However only seeing a handful of cookies being returned. Testing on Techcrunch.com which through firecookie shows 50+ cookies, through above method, I see 3. Am I expecting 1st, 3rd & HttpOnly Cookies through this routine?

Comment: Through the proxy, I'm seeing ~30 cookies in the Response. Can't currently tally that with firecookie as can't restart Firefox currently to install it. But I don't know the innards of BrowserMob Proxy I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm only seeing the following ones: PREF, ID, external_8331216_end_user_id, OAID, CfP, JEB2, MUNAUTHID, UNAUTHID, CUNAUTHID. The obvious ones like Google Analytics aren't showing up.

Comment: Did some investigation, and the only ones I'm seeing are those passed as part of the header set-cookie request. Any reason why the rest are not showing up?

Comment: I'm afraid that's the extent on my knowledge on the BrowserMob Proxy - I haven't delved that deep into it, and the lib I wrote can only deal with what that proxy is giving it. Sorry I can't offer any more help

Comment: If I have a .net project, how do I start to use this?